# Issue with loading a button based on the loggedin state

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying different ways to display a conditional button based on the athtentication state, but i keep getting into trouble. I have an app.js that defines the stacknavigator, which adds a button to the header giving the option to log out if authenticated.
I wrote a handleLogout function that should perform this.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Image, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
import Loading from './Loading';
import SignUp from './SignUp';
import Login from './Login';
import Main from './Main';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

// eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
handleLogOut = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  firebase
    .auth()
    .signOut()
    .then(() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Login'))
    .catch(error => this.setState({errorMessage: error.message}));
};

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Loading: Loading,
    SignUp: SignUp,
    Login: Login,
    Main: Main,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Loading',

    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerLeft: null,
      headerRight: () => {
          let button = this.loggedIn? (
          <Button
          onPress={this.handleLogOut}
          title="Log-out"
          color="#fff"
          />
        )
        : 
        (
          <Button
          onPress={() => alert('Please log in')}
          title="Log-in"
          color="#fff"
          />
        )
          return button;
      },

      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: '#c6f1e7',
      },
      headerTintColor: '#59616e',
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontFamily: 'Raleway-Regular',
        fontWeight: '400',
      },
    },
  },
);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

App.js calls on loading.js where the value for loggedin is declared, based on the authentciation state and then loads either main.js or sign-up. in this case the main page is loaded, which means that someone is authenticated:

```
// Loading.js
import React from 'react';
import {View, ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

export default class Loading extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.setState({ loggedIn: true })
        this.props.navigation.navigate(user ? 'Main' : 'SignUp');
      } else {
        this.setState({ loggedIn: false })
      }
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#c6f1e7',
  },
});
```

Now the page redirects to main and shows the welcome message, which indicates that the user is logged in, but the button in the header is saying 'log-in' as well, which means the button is not chosen well. I assume that this is because the loggedin value is not read and it automatically sets it on loggedin: false.

Here is the code for main.js

```
// Main.js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import Kowops from './Kowops';
import Scan from './Scan';
import Wallet from './Wallet';

export class Main extends React.Component {
  state = { currentUser: null }
  componentDidMount() {
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth()
    this.setState({ currentUser })
}
  render() {
    const { currentUser } = this.state

  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>
          Hidiho {currentUser && currentUser.email}!
        </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
 const bottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Main: {screen: Main},
    Kowops: {screen:Kowops},
    Scan: {screen:Scan},
    Wallet: {screen:Wallet},
  },
  {
    //initialRouteName: 'Main',
    tabBarOptions: {
      initialRouteName: 'Main',
      activeTintColor: '#59616e',
      inactiveTintColor: '#a9a9a9',
      style: {
        backgroundColor: '#c6f1e7',
     }
    },
  });

export default createAppContainer(bottomTabNavigator);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    }
  })
```

So I need to figure out how to ensure that the value of isloggedin is read properly and the script loads the right button.

Does anyone have a clue?

Thanks in advance!!

Tim

Comment: what version of react navigation are you using.

Comment: "react-navigation": "^4.1.1",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is that you can't use state across different components without passing them as props or through navigation params in this case. You can't use the useNavigation hook outside of a functional component so you should pass the navigation object around when you need it outside of a component (handleLogout is not a component).

Here are some alterations I would make, however I would suggest that you will need to make further changes based on the idea that you can use navigation params to pass information between screens. See more here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html.

App.js

DefaultNavigationOptions can be a function which has a navigation prop, this is the navigation object you can use to get params or navigate in the context of the router.

remove that eslint exception because you don't need it, just properly declare the variable. Remove the "this" from you handleLogout function call because it is not a class attribute. Use navigation.getParam to get the isLoggedIn variable which you can pass in the navigate function call.

```
const handleLogout = navigation => {
    firebase
        .auth()
        .signOut()
        .then(() => navigation.navigate('Login'))
        .catch(error => this.setState({errorMessage: error.message}));
}

...

defaultNavigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
    headerRight: () => {

        const isLoggedIn = navigation.getParam('isLoggedIn', false);
        let button = isLoggedIn ? (
          <Button
            onPress={() => handleLogOut(navigation)}
            title="Log-out"
            color="#fff"
          />
        ) : ...
    } ...
```

Now Loading.js
Here you need to add a navigation param to your navigate call which can then be used in the header

```
 ...
 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {

    this.props.navigation.navigate('Main', {isLoggedIn: true});
  } else {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('SignUp', {isLoggedIn: false});
  }
});
```

here is a modified version of your code in snack that you can see will get the logged in param and show the logout button https://snack.expo.io/@dannyhw/intrigued-graham-crackers
You will need to make further changes to fix other functionality because I only changed the minimum to show that you can use the navigation param.

Comment: Thanks a lot Danny, that helped me fix things and it now works perfectly well.

Comment: Glad I could help :)